# Regular cross-sections of a dodecahedron; analogous sections of 4-polytopes

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, convex-polytopes, polyhedra

One can intersect a dodecahedron with a plane and
obtain an equilateral triangle, a square, a regular pentagon,
a regular hexagon, and a regular decagon:

---

[image]

---

[image]

 
 
 
 
 
<sub>(Image of 6- and 10-gon from [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dodecahedron.html).)</sub>

---

> **Q1**. Does there exist a regular 7-gon, 8-gon, or 9-gon cross-section of
>   the dodecahedron?

I can achieve, e.g., an irregular octagon, but not a regular octagon.

> **Q2**. Can all five Platonic solids be achieved as cross-sections of one of the
>   [six regular 4-polytopes](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_regular_4-polytope)?

I haven't given this much thought, but the 120-cell seems the most likely candidate,
as its facets are dodecahedra.

Comment: I remember a related problem from a high school exam involving an octahedron.  I suspect there is no regular polyhedron with a regular heptagonal or octahedronal cross section: one needs a pyramid or prism  to achieve such.  If  I can, I will provide a sketch of justification later.

Comment: In fact, I suspect the existence of slice S of polyhedron P implies G(S) is a subgroup (maybe even normal) of G(P). I am talking symmetry groups here.

Comment: The square exists as a slice of a dodecahedron, but $D_8$ is not a subgroup of $C_2 \times A_5$. Specifically, the only order-$8$ subgroups of the latter are its Sylow $2$-subgroups, which are $C_2 \times C_2 \times C_2$.